# php - Unsuccessful url RewriteRules, .htaccess and/or url interpreting set-up

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, interpreter

My issue is I have an unsuccessful .htaccess & url interpreting set-up and I hope to get help because I couldn't solve my issue on my own.

## **my symptoms**

1. I have no problem with my sole *index.php* when the url is `www.domain.p.ht` or `www.domain.p.ht/index.php`
2. if url is `www.domain.p.ht/yazılar` again it displays as I expect
3. But if url is `www.domain.p.ht/iletişim` **OR** `www.domain.p.ht/etiketler`, html prints the same page as if the url is `www.domain.p.ht/yazılar`

   ## **my whole .htaccess code**

   ```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /    

   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]    

   RewriteRule ^yazılar/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?rd_sayfa=yazilar&rd_ozne=$1&rd_nesne=$2 [L]    

   RewriteRule ^yazılar/(.+)$ index.php?rd_sayfa=yazilar&rd_ozne=$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^etiketler/(.+)$ index.php?rd_sayfa=etiketler&rd_ozne=$1 [L]    

   RewriteRule ^iletişim$ index.php?rd_sayfa=iletisim [L]
   RewriteRule ^etiketler$ index.php?rd_sayfa=etiketler [L]
   RewriteRule ^yazılar$ index.php?rd_sayfa=yazilar [L]
   RewriteRule ^site-haritası$ index.php?rd_sayfa=site_haritasi [L]
   RewriteRule ^hakkında$ index.php?rd_sayfa=hakkinda [L]
   RewriteRule ^ara$ index.php?rd_sayfa=arama [L]
   RewriteRule ^yorum-doğrula$ index.php?rd_sayfa=yorum_dogrula [L]
   RewriteRule ^eposta-doğrula$ index.php?rd_sayfa=eposta_dogrula [L]
   RewriteRule ^yorumunuz-için-teşekkür-ederim$ index.php?rd_sayfa=yorum_onay [L]
   RewriteRule ^epostanız-için-teşekkür-ederim$ index.php?rd_sayfa=eposta_onay [L]
   ```

## my php codes to interpret the url and determine page identifier variable which is `$sayfa`

```
$sayfa = '';

$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if(!empty($_GET)) {$getsayaci = count($_GET);}

$url_check01 = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$url_check02 = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');


if (isset($_GET['rd_sayfa']) AND $_GET['rd_sayfa'] != '')
{
    if ($getsayaci == 1)
    {
        if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'yazılar') {$sayfa = 'yazilar';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'iletişim') {$sayfa = 'iletisim';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'site-haritası') {$sayfa = 'site_haritasi';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'etiketler') {$sayfa = 'etiketler';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'yorum-doğrula') {$sayfa = 'yorum_dogrula';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'eposta-doğrula') {$sayfa = 'eposta_dogrula';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'yorumunuz-için-teşekkür-ederim') {$sayfa = 'yorum_onay';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'epostanız-için-teşekkür-ederim') {$sayfa = 'eposta_onay';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'hakkında') {$sayfa = 'hakkinda';}
        else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'ara') {$sayfa = 'arama';}
        else {$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';}
    }

    else if (isset($_GET['rd_ozne']) AND $_GET['rd_ozne'] != '')
    {
        if ($getsayaci == 2)
        {
            if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'yazılar') {$sayfa = 'yazarin_yazilari';}
            else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'etiketler') {$sayfa = 'bir_etiket';}
            else if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'ara') {$sayfa = 'aranan';}
            else {$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';}
        }

        else if (isset($_GET['rd_nesne']) AND $_GET['rd_nesne'] != '' AND $getsayaci == 3)
        {
            if ($_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'yazılar') 
            {
                $sayfa = 'spesifik_yazi';
            }
            else
            {
                $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
    }
}

else if ($url_check01 == '/index.php' AND $url_check02 == '/index.php' AND ($actual_link = "site1" OR $actual_link = "site2" ))
{
$sayfa = 'anasayfa';
}

else
{
$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I have 3rd symptom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the answer of Kabir, I assumed with a stronger feeling that my `.htaccess` structure is correct &  and my main problem is false interpretation of the `URL`.
Since the html always prints the same output for different links, I again assumed that my `$sayfa` value doesn't change according to the link.
And after 4 days, I noticed that I should have been used `==` instead of `=` with all `$_GET['rd_sayfa'] = 'whatever'` because **a single** `=` manipulates the value of `$sayfa` while `==` only compare the values. So I replaced them all to **`$_GET['rd_sayfa'] == 'yazılar'`** and now my links are working.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using .htaccess to change the URL and i a using like this and it is working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(services|testimonialdisclaimer|privacypolicy)\.php$ index.php?page=$1
```

So may be you can try like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(iletişim|etiketler|yazılar)$ index.php?rd_sayfa=$1
```

Comment: by your kind help, I learnt a shorter way to write RewriteRule but my symptoms are still same 100%. Maybe my main problem is false interpretation of the url.